# String resources for options

Tags: java, android, string, random

I making a random textview and I have a problem. How can I put strings resources from xml to **String options**[]:

```
String options[] = {"abc","def","ghi",}

    Random rand = new Random();
    final int random = rand.nextInt(3);

    textfacts.setText(options[random]);
```

I want to use these strings in Strings options:

```
<string name="1">abc</string>
<string name="2">abc</string>
<string name="3">abc</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
String options[] = {getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING_NAME_1),getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING_NAME_1)}
```

Or You can add array from string.xml by this way

```
String options[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.YOUR_STRING_ARRAY_NAME)
```

Comment: When I use this my app start crashing :/

Answer (score 0):

> In res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
<string name="world">World</string>

<string-array name="java">
    <item>@string/hello</item>
    <item>@string/world</item>
</string-array>
```

in any activity (java)

```
String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.java)
textView.setText(some_array[0])
```

in Kotlin

```
 val some_array= (activity.resources.getStringArray(R.string.java).toMutableList())
textView.text=some_array[0]
```